# What does the pink note left by Taiga say?

Tags: toradora

In [Episode 25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urbfaxHt64s&t=11m33s) near 11:23, Ryuji goes to Taiga's condo and finds a note. What is written on it?

[image]

Comment: If crunchyroll allowed SS (damn DRM) I would post one.

Comment: Do you have the timestamp when the note was shown?

Comment: @Memor-X Ah, that's why I couldn't find it. It's in episode _25_ (edited question to reflect that).

Comment: added a better one since the image it a bit sharper and got a screen shot of the note

Answer (score 7):

The text of the note is:

> 竜児へ
>
> 竜児___ね…ずっとずっと自分なんかが
>   ___愛されるはずないと思ってた。
>   でもそれは逃げてただけなのかも知れない。
>   自身がもてないのを親のせいに…周りのせいにして…
>   でも、竜児は私をそのまま愛してくれた…。
>   自分に誇りをもって…
>
> 竜児を愛したいから。
>
> 相坂大河

There are two blanks (on the first two lines of the body) that cannot be made out because of the pen in the way. However, this turns out to be pretty much the same as the narration that Taiga does starting around 10:28, so we can fill in the blanks: the first blank is 私 and the second blank is 誰かに. Now, a rough translation:

> Ryuuji,
>
> Ryuuji, I... always thought that there was no way anybody would ever love me. But maybe I was just running away [from my problems?]. I blamed my lack of confidence on my parents... on my situation. But even so, you loved me the way I was. I'll be proud of myself...
>
> Because I want to love you, Ryuuji.
>
> Aisaka Taiga

The letter omits the lines to the effect of "I won't run away anymore; I'll change; I'll accept myself" which are present in her narration.

Comment: Ahhh, so she's actually narrating the letter

Comment: Did you just read it from the note, or listen to the narration and type it out?

Comment: @nhahtdh lol I didn't realize at first that it was the same as the narration, so I read it from the note. It took a lot of squinting.